# Using MicroLite on SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I set up a SQLite db with the same schema as my existing SQL server db and noted the following...

1. SQLite field names (and presumably everything else) are case sensitive.
2. MicroLite's SqlBuilder appears to insert the prefix 'dbo.' before the table name, which SQLite doesn't like...

This query works...

```
query = new SqlQuery("SELECT [ClubID], [Name] FROM [Clubs] WHERE [ClubID] = @p0", 3);

clubs = session.Fetch<MicroLiteClub>(query);
```

This one doesn't...

```
query = SqlBuilder.Select("*")
                  .From(typeof(MicroLiteClub))
                  .Where("ClubID = @p0", 3)
                  .OrWhere("ClubID = @p1", 22)
                  .OrderByDescending("Name")
                  .ToSqlQuery();

clubs = session.Fetch<MicroLiteClub>(query);
```

MicroLite logged: "no such table: dbo.Clubs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because SQLite doesn't support table schemas like MS SQL Server does.

In the hand crafted query, you are not specifying a schame for the table `FROM [Clubs]` however in your mapping attribute you will have specified `dbo` as the schema like this:

```
[Table(schema: "dbo", name: "Clubs")]
```

The `SqlBuilder` doesn't know what SQL Dialect is in use so if a schame is present on the table mapping, it will be used. This means that it would generate `FROM [dbo].[Clubs]`. To rectify this, simply remove the schema value on the `TableAttribute` as is optional from MicroLite 2.1 onwards.

On a side note, MicroLite 2.1 introduced support for `In` in the SqlBuilder fluent API so you could change:

```
.Where("ClubID = @p0", 3)
.OrWhere("ClubID = @p1", 22)
```

to

```
.Where("ClubID").In(3, 22)
```